# How to rename items by assigning sequential number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @OperatorPrice TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL, DealerId INT NULL, DealerName VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

and sample data:

```
INSERT INTO @OperatorPrice 
(
    ID, DealerId, DealerName
)
VALUES
  (226, 1,  'WestCarDealer')
, (112, 1,  'WestCarDealer')
, (266, 2, 'AO')
, (112, 2, 'AO')
, (93,  3, 'Best on the West')
, (93,  3, 'Best on the West')
```

What I want is to rename all dealers to 'Dealer1', 'Dealer2', 'Dealer3'. The number should be assigned in ascending order: `AO` should be renamed to 'Dealer1' cause `AO` starts with `A`, `Best on the West` should be renamed to `Dealer2` cause it starts with `B`, `WestCarDealer` should be renamed to `Dealer3` cause it starts with `W`.

So the desired output  should looks like this:

```
  (226, 1, 'Dealer3')
, (112, 1, 'Dealer3')
, (266, 2, 'Dealer1')
, (112, 2, 'Dealer1')
, (93,  3, 'Dealer2')
, (93,  3, 'Dealer2')
```

Approximate quantity of unique `DealerName`'s is 50 dealers.

How can I rename car dealers in that way?

I've tried to use cursors for this purpose, but could not store the number to increment.

Comment: Is this just for obfuscating data or something? And to be perfectly honest you are struggling here because your table is not normalized. The DealerName should be in one and only one location in your database, most like the Dealers table. Storing it in another table is an indication of a poor design.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah, I know. My knowledge of SQL is very poor and I am not designer of this tables, but I would like to find a way to do this. I am not going to update table by this data permanently, it is necessary just for temp table. I am really ashamed by asking this question if this question is very stupid, but I am doing my best. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an CTE to update the table variable

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NewVal = concat('Dealer',dense_rank() over ( order by DealerName))
 From  @OperatorPrice
)
Update cte Set DealerName = NewVal
```

**Updated @OperatorPrice**

```
ID  DealerId    DealerName
226 1           Dealer3
112 1           Dealer3
266 2           Dealer1
112 2           Dealer1
93  3           Dealer2
93  3           Dealer2
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds John. Well done as always!!

Comment: @SeanLange "I'm going to Disney World!"

Comment: @SeanLange Seriously?  Am I that old?

Comment: Hardly. I had to go look up that and I am guessing it is in reference to the commercials from the late 80s that had a resurgence about 10 years ago. I have never been a big TV watcher so it missed me. Besides I was already a bit fuzzy most of my day during that time....hic....college

Comment: @StepUp Always happy to help