# Find overlap time between Start date time and end date time with another table

Tags: sql-server

Need to find the overlap time- START_DATUM and END_DATUM is the datetime field which holds starting or ending date and time of downtime

In below example only Internal downtime(mentioned field as internalDowntime) can be overlapped with Other Downtime(mentioned field as OtherDowntime). Ultimate aim is find the total overlap time in minutes as another field

Appreciate if somebody could help me to sort this out

```
SELECT deck.ID_DECKUNGSBEITRAG,

       (
           SELECT TOP (1)
                  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, lr.START_DATUM, lr.END_DATUM) / 60.0
           FROM dbo.LEITSTAND lr
               INNER JOIN dbo.STILLSTANDSZEIT s
                   ON lr.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT = s.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT
               INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUKTIONSANLAGE P
                   ON lr.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = P.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE
           WHERE lr.PRODUKTION_TYP = 'S'
                 AND s.TYP = 'R'
                 AND lr.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = l.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE
                 AND lr.START_DATUM < l.START_DATUM
           ORDER BY lr.START_DATUM DESC
       ) setuptime,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.START_DATUM, l.END_DATUM) / 60.0 runtime,
       (
           SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, le.START_DATUM, le.END_DATUM) / 60.0)
           FROM dbo.STILLSTANDSZEIT s
               INNER JOIN dbo.LEITSTAND le
                   ON le.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT = s.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT
           WHERE s.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT = hs.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT
       ) internalDowntime,
       (
           SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ZEIT_VON, ZEIT_BIS) / 60.0)
           FROM dbo.PRODUKTIONSANLAGE_AUSFALLZEIT
           WHERE ZEIT_VON >= l.START_DATUM
                 AND ZEIT_VON <= l.END_DATUM
                 AND ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = p.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE
       ) OtherDowntime,
       p.STUNDENSATZ_GRENZKOSTEN
FROM dbo.DECKUNGSBEITRAG deck
    INNER JOIN dbo.HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT hs
        ON deck.CHARGE = hs.CHARGE_NUMMER
    INNER JOIN dbo.LEITSTAND l
        ON l.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT = hs.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT
    INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUKTIONSANLAGE p
        ON p.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = l.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE        
WHERE deck.CHARGE = 'CHG0116112945'
      AND deck.ID_MANDANT = 1
```

Comment: Sorry for so late example, however could you write your question like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432461/how-to-rename-items-by-assigning-sequential-number    This question has sample data and desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution,

```
;WITH AllDownTime AS
(
    /* Overlapping DownTimeInternal DownTimeExternal */ 
    SELECT IIF(i.StartTime < e.StartTime, i.StartTime, e.StartTime) StartTime,
           IIF(i.EndTime < e.EndTime, e.EndTime, i.EndTime) EndTime
      FROM dbo.DownTimeInternal i
     INNER JOIN dbo.DownTimeExternal e
             ON i.StartTime < e.EndTime AND e.StartTime < i.EndTime  
UNION ALL
    /* Non overlapping DownTimeInternal */
    SELECT i.StartTime, i.EndTime
      FROM dbo.DownTimeInternal i
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                         FROM dbo.DownTimeExternal e
                        WHERE i.StartTime < e.EndTime AND e.StartTime < i.EndTime)
UNION ALL
    /* Non overlapping DownTimeExternal */
    SELECT e.StartTime, e.EndTime
      FROM dbo.DownTimeExternal e
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                        FROM dbo.DownTimeInternal i
                       WHERE e.StartTime < i.EndTime AND i.StartTime < e.EndTime)
)

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,StartTime,EndTime))/60.0 
  FROM AllDownTime
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to find time overlapping is:

```
(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)
```

As you said you have two tables. So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID 
AND T1.StartA <= T2.EndB
AND T1.EndA >= T2.StartB
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I provided the complete query , I’m expecting another column in the query output which should pull total overlap time(respective with internal and other downtime) in minutes . Not sure how to achieve it, not interested to use cursor

Comment: It does not allow me to edit the question, kindly look below, which shows with input data

Answer (score 0):

Production time is always includes downtimes if there is a downtime (internal and other), idea is calculate exact production time, excluding the downtimes. Problem here is, internal downtime may overlap with other downtime.

```
SELECT runtime  ---internalDowntime-OtherDowntime AS productiontime  based on overlapping
FROM
(
    SELECT deck.ID_DECKUNGSBEITRAG, 
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.START_DATUM, l.END_DATUM) / 60.0 runtime, --which includes downtime, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, le.START_DATUM, le.END_DATUM) / 60.0)
        FROM dbo.STILLSTANDSZEIT s
             INNER JOIN dbo.LEITSTAND le ON le.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT = s.ID_STILLSTANDSZEIT
        WHERE s.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT = hs.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT
    ) internalDowntime, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ZEIT_VON, ZEIT_BIS) / 60.0)
        FROM dbo.PRODUKTIONSANLAGE_AUSFALLZEIT
        WHERE ZEIT_VON >= l.START_DATUM
              AND ZEIT_VON <= l.END_DATUM
              AND ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = p.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE
    ) OtherDowntime
    FROM dbo.DECKUNGSBEITRAG deck
         INNER JOIN dbo.HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT hs ON deck.CHARGE = hs.CHARGE_NUMMER
         INNER JOIN dbo.LEITSTAND l ON l.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT = hs.ID_HERSTELLVORSCHRIFT
         INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUKTIONSANLAGE p ON p.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE = l.ID_PRODUKTIONSANLAGE
    WHERE deck.CHARGE = 'CHG0116112945'
          AND deck.ID_MANDANT = 1
) temp;
```

Date format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

[**Production start and endtime (runtime)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLQgC.png)

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2016-12-09 01:00:49.203','2016-12-12 22:30:04.787')/60.0       =  93.500000
```

[**Internal Downtime**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwze0.png)
1st row 1 hour and second row 5 hours, total 6 hours

[**Other Downtime**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFrsB.png)

1st row      `SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2016-12-10 06:00:00.000','2016-12-12 06:00:00.000')/60.0  =48.000000`
Highlighted one is inclusive with internal downtime except 1 hour, hence totally 49 hours

Excepting final output(production time) is  93.50 – 6 -  49  = 38.5